# Intellij IDEA Runtime Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: intellij-idea, resources, runtime, maven-3, heap-memory

**Information:java: The system is out of resources.**
Information:java: Consult the following stack trace for details.
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.enterClass(ClassReader.java:2419)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.unboxedType(Types.java:3987)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.unboxedTypeOrType(Types.java:3998)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$ArgumentExpressionKind.standaloneKind(DeferredAttr.java:1135)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredChecker.visitLiteral(DeferredAttr.java:1296)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLiteral.accept(JCTree.java:2037)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$FilterScanner.scan(DeferredAttr.java:913)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr.isDeferred(DeferredAttr.java:1100)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribArgs(Attr.java:670)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1816)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3250)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1825)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'RecordLinkage'
Information:javac 1.8.0_131 was used to compile java sources
Information:20-06-2017 12:06 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 41s 44ms
**Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError**

Comment: Feel free to file a bug here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. Attach idea.log and build.log with debug info (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).